# self reference tree structure

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using C# with entity framework core and sql server.

I want to model something like a composite structure but have some problems saving the structure in the repostiroy.

This is the error I get:

> Unable to save changes because a circular dependency was detected in the data to be saved: 'LogicAnd [Added] ParentComponent { 'ParentComponentId1' } <- Condition [Added] <- CompDer { 'CompDerId' } LogicAnd [Added]'.

## Base class:

```
public abstract class Component
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public int ParentComponentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Component ParentComponent { get; set; }

    public  abstract bool Evaluate();
}
```

## Leaf class:

```
public class Condition : Component
{
    public virtual ValueExpression ValueIzq { get; set; }
    public virtual ValueExpression ValueDer { get; set; }
    public String Operation {get;set;}
    public override bool Evaluete(){....}
}
```

## Abstract composite class:

```
public abstract class LogicExpression : Component
{
    public virtual Component CompIzq { get; set; }
    public virtual Component CompDer { get; set; }

}
```

## Composite derived classes:

```
public class LogicAnd : LogicExpression
{
    public override bool Evaluete()
    {
           .....
    }
}


public class LogicOr : LogicExpression
{
    public override bool Evaluete()
    {
           .....
    }
}
```

## Context:

```
public DbSet<Condition> Conditions { get; set; }
public DbSet<LogicAnd> LogicAnds { get; set; }
public DbSet<LogicOr> LogicOrs { get; set; }


protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Component>().ToTable("Components");
}

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is there any chance that those objects will be retrieved or queried individually? If not, it's probably a better idea to store the entire graph as XML or JSON and deserialize it when you need it. Should you need to query the data in the database, you can use the XML functions available since 2005 or the JSON functions added in 2016

Comment: There is no restriction in the implementation so I can try that

Comment: You should show the code that throws the exception.